# Catching MailApp.sendEmail delivery failure

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to catch email delivery failure in an app script. I thought surrounding MailApp.sendEmail in a try catch would work like so:

```
function headache(){
 Logger.log("Before Try");
  try{
    Logger.log("before sendEmail");
    MailApp.sendEmail("ThisAFake@email.address", "Ima Error", "");
    Logger.log("after sendEmail");
  }catch(err){
   Logger.log("In catch");
    MailApp.sendEmail("ThisAReal@email.address", "Ima catched Error", "");
    } 
  Logger.log("After Try");
}
```

but this is the output im getting:

```
Before Try
before sendEmail
after sendEmail
After Try
```

Is there a way to catch mail send failures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Email sending is deferred and there is no way to catch this error.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm from my own testing that in 2022, try catch will successfully catch on an exception caused by an invalid recipient email address being passed to MailApp.sendMail({options});