# Add additional email recipient to "summary of failures" email sent by Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there any way to add an additional recipient to the Summary of Failures... email that's sent by Google when the scripts fail? I can't seem to find a way to do that.

Comment: Autoforward it to another email?

Comment: @I'-'I thanks, unfortunately the auto-forwarding feature was disabled by the company gmail admins. Is there another way to achieve the same result?

Comment: Based from this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15348952/catching-mailapp-sendemail-delivery-failure), email sending is deferred and there is no way to catch this error. You may also check this [link](https://digitalinspiration.com/failure-email-4488) for the *Summary of failures for Google Apps Script – Troubleshoot*.